# Replacing words using multiple rules

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

This function is supposed to replace matches with a shortened version using multiple rules rather than just a single one.  For the word `counter`, `coun` gets replaced by `k`, resulting in the shortened word `kter`.

But I am struggling for the case where the replacement has to be done at the end.  So that `family` gets replaced by `faml` (replacing `ily` match with `l`).

```
(defun shorten-word-b ()
  "Shortens a word according to specific rules."

  (interactive)

  (let* ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
     (s (car bounds))
     (case-fold-search nil)
     (p (point-marker)))

    (when s
      (goto-char s)
      (cond
       ;;-----------------------------------------------
       ((looking-at (regexp-opt
           '("cog" "col" "com" "con" "cor" "cum" "coun") "\\<\\("))
        (replace-match "k"))
       ;;-----------------------------------------------       
       ((looking-at (regexp-opt
           '("ley" "ily" "ly") "\\)\\>"))
        (replace-match "l"))
       ;;-----------------------------------------------
       (t nil))
      (goto-char p))
    (set-marker p nil)))
```

Here are some examples

```
Before: Counter
After: kter

Before: family
After: faml
```

Where point can be placed anywhere, with next character being a character of word.

Comment: Please add "Before:" and "After:" samples including the location of point.

Comment: @PhilHudson: `bounds-of-things-at-point` returns a dotted pair whose `car` is the beginning of the `thing`-at-point and whose `cdr` is the end of it (in this case the `thing` is a word). So `(goto-char s)` puts `point` at the beginning of the word in preparation for the `cond`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but here is a variation of what you wrote above that works in all the cases I've tried:

```el
(defun shorten-word-b ()
  "Shortens the word at point according to specific rules."

  (interactive)

  (let* ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
         (s (car bounds))
         (case-fold-search nil)
         (p (point-marker)))
    
    (when s
      (goto-char s)
      (cond
       ;;-----------------------------------------------
       ;; deal with prefixes
       ((looking-at (concat "\\<"
                            (regexp-opt
                             '("cog" "col" "com" "con" "cor" "cum" "coun"))))
        (replace-match "k"))
       ;;-----------------------------------------------       
       ;; deal with suffixes - be careful not to overstep the bounds
       ((search-forward-regexp (concat (regexp-opt '("ley" "ily" "ly")) "\\>") (cdr bounds) t)
        (replace-match "l"))
       ;;-----------------------------------------------
       (t nil))
      (goto-char p))
    (set-marker p nil)))
```

The tests I tried:

```
cognition
confidence
counter
columnar
cumulative
contiguous
correlative
abscond
score
scum
scoliosis
discount
discography
family
oleley
only
lye
familiar
unrelated
not-a-match
```

Unfortunately, neither regexp catches the case of a prefix or a suffix being the whole "word": `con` becomes `k` and `ily` becomes `l`. You have to complicate the regexps to catch those cases and *not* do the contraction.

Comment: There is no need for complication, making replacement still acceptable.

Comment: Fixed a bug: check the edit history to see what I changed.

Comment: You are quite right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the second argument to the second `regexp-opt` form. That argument gets *prefixed*; your call implies that you want it to be suffixed, but `regexp-opt` does not offer you that facility.

What you need is something like this (untested):

```
((looking-at
   (concat
    (regexp-opt '("ley" "ily" "ly")) "\\b"))  
  (replace-match "l"))
```

where `"\\b"` is the word-boundary matcher.

Comment: It's worse than that: if `point` is at the `f` of `family`, then using `looking-at` to seach for the `ily` at the end is just not going to match. It has to be at the `i` of `ily`. I think `looking-at` is the wrong interface here.

Comment: Good point. I'll add a comment asking for details.

Comment: What would be your recommendation that replaces `looking-at`?  Would the change apply to all cases?

Comment: Should I continue with `(insert (replace-regexp-in-string` as I had done before?

Comment: @PhilHudson I progressed with `((looking-at (concat "[[:alpha:]]+[-]?" "\\(" (regexp-opt '("ley" "ily" "ly")) "\\)\\>"))`.  Why does it turn `family` to `famil`, rather than `faml`?

Comment: That's a different question!

Comment: `looking-at` is probably fine for prefixes, but it's not OK for suffixes: you'd have to back up over the whole suffix (which you don't know beforehand) to be able to apply `looking-at`.

Comment: Would it make sense to use `search-forward-regexp` for prefixes as well?

Comment: Probably. You *might* even be able to use a single regexp for both prefixes and suffixes.